# How to show a animation on vue js whenever the app is accessed?

Tags: html, vue.js, animation, vue-component

i want to show some animation like my websites title and logo whenever  the home page is requested i.e.., to show some animation images whenever the website is requested before showing the actual content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `state` that is set to `false`  by default, like `pageIsLoaded = false` then change it to true once the page is loaded.

And do some logic like:

```
if (!pageIsLoaded) {
  *do something..*
} else {
  *do something..*
}
```

Use this reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html